# Catch any touch in the screen in a service

Tags: android, service, screen

I need a service that know if the user is touching the screen anywhere. If user doesn't touch the screen in a time, I launched a intent to the browser. Someone can help me. I cann´t find the code of how to capture any touch on screen in a service and I cann't think in any solution. Sorry for my English and thanks.

Comment: you cant do it using services, you can listen for touch event using a background activity. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write your code inside the following method:

```
public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. So this method, i writte it in my activity, rigth?

Comment: A Service is a component which runs in the background, without    interacting with the user. You can follow the link for better understanding: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: You have to write the onUserInteraction method in every Activity u want to provide.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. I try this method. The problem is, i need catch the events out of my activity, for example in the start screen. For this reason i try catch the events in the service because the service running out of the main activity. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can I do this with a BroadcastReceiver instead of a service?